# MATLAB Index exceeds matrix dimensions in programming for explicit euler

Tags: matlab

I keep getting this error. I received this error after I corrected for logical integer error. The only way I could think of programming this was defining the initial value and then start euler's method at the next t value since it uses the previous solution to find the next one. But by doing this I am getting this error? I'm unsure how to fix it. I tried to end one step from my final value but that didn't work either. Thanks for the help. For the problem we had to create the function and call it. I was initially using n=8.

```
function [exeuler] = pb3(n)
%using explicit euler to solve ODE with input n and outputting exeuler as
%the answer
%n=steps t,y are initial conditions
h=3/n;
t=logical((1+h):h:4);
back=logical(t-h);

exeuler(1)=2; %defines the initial value
exeuler(t)=exeuler(back)+h*(t.^2-(2*exeuler(back)/t));

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am sorry, but you haven't showed much of effort. For the future, please provide the complete code (i.e. with example function and so on). This is very unclear.

I think your problem is in these lines:

```
t=logical((1+h):h:4);
exeuler(t)=exeuler(back)+h*(t.^2-(2*exeuler(back)/t));
```

cause t is a vector. You are calling vector with non-integer values as index. Then, I guess, you get the wrong amount of exeuler(t)'s which leads to the error.
And for-loop is missing, isn't it? Because you don't use the Euler method stepwise andd therefore f(t+1) doesn't really depend on f(t).
So, my advice in general would be **not to correct this error, but to rethink your algorithm.**